# getting error when integrating ccavenue in my django project

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, payment-gateway, ccavenue, django-deployment

```
# ccav_app/ccav_utils.py

from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import padding as sym_padding
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
import base64
import os

def pad(data):
    padder = padding.PKCS7(128).padder()
    padded_data = padder.update(data) + padder.finalize()
    return padded_data

def unpad(data):
    unpadder = padding.PKCS7(128).unpadder()
    unpadded_data = unpadder.update(data) + unpadder.finalize()
    return unpadded_data

def derive_key(secret_key):
    salt = os.urandom(16)  # Generate a random salt (16 bytes)
    kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
        algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
        iterations=100000,
        salt=salt,
        length=32,  # Use 32 bytes for a 256-bit key
        backend=default_backend()
    )
    key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(secret_key.encode()))
    return key


def encrypt(plain_text, secret_key):
    key = derive_key(secret_key)
    iv = os.urandom(16)
    cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.CFB(iv), backend=default_backend())
    encryptor = cipher.encryptor()
    encrypted_text = encryptor.update(plain_text.encode()) + encryptor.finalize()
    return base64.b64encode(iv + encrypted_text).decode()

def decrypt(cipher_text, secret_key):
    key = derive_key(secret_key)
    data = base64.b64decode(cipher_text.encode())
    iv = data[:16]
    cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.CFB(iv), backend=default_backend())
    decryptor = cipher.decryptor()
    decrypted_text = decryptor.update(data[16:]) + decryptor.finalize()
    return unpad(decrypted_text).decode()
```

this is my ccavutil.py file where i am gettig data and secret key through encrypt and decrypt

but getting error

ValueError at /cc/

```
Invalid key size (352) for AES.
```

Request Method:POSTRequest URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000/cc/Django Version:4.2.1Exception Type:ValueErrorException Value:Invalid key size (352) for AES.

I want to integrate the ccavenue payment gateway in my website but getting error

Answer (score 0):

might be issue in secret key or your derive_key function

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).